# Angular add object inside of object in localstorage

Tags: angular, typescript

how can i specify when setting localestorage, to add object inside the object?

**.ts**

```
export function getFromLocalStorage<T>(storageKey: string): T {
    return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(storageKey));
}

    export const setToLocalStorage = (storageKey: string, key: string, value: any) =>
        localStorage.setItem(storageKey, JSON.stringify({
            ...getFromLocalStorage(storageKey),
            [key]: value
        }));
    
    setToLocalStorage('myObj', 'personalInfo', formValuesArray);
```

**this is the value how it creates:**

```
"personalInfo":[
      {
         "name":"test",
         "surname":"test2",
      }
   ],
```

**this is how i want it to create:**

```
  "personalInfo":{
      "underageChildInfo":[
         {
        "name":"test",
         "surname":"test2",
         }
      ]
   },
```

Comment: Provide setToLocalStorage and getFromLocalStorage functions too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is plain javascript but should work exactly the same in Typescript:

```
class UnderageChildInfo{
  constructor(name, surname) {
    this.name = name;
    this.surname = surname;
  }
}

class PersonalInfo{
  constructor(underageChildInfo) {
    this.underageChildInfo = underageChildInfo;
  }
}

function run() {
  var underageChildInfo = new UnderageChildInfo("Bob", "Smith");
  var personalInfo = new PersonalInfo(underageChildInfo);

  localStorage.setItem('personalInfo', JSON.stringify(personalInfo));

  var pi2 = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('personalInfo'));

  console.log(pi2.underageChildInfo.name + " " + pi2.underageChildInfo.surname);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to build a dictionary. In that case this reference could help you:

```
var elements= [{"name": "???"}, {"name": "###"}];
var dict = {"personal_info": {"underageChildInfo": ""}}
dict["personal_info"]["underage_info"] = JSON.stringify(elements);
console.log(dict)
```